# Passing variable to jenkins yaml podTemplate

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am using Jenkins with the kubernetes plugin to run my jobs and I need to run a pipeline that:

1. builds a docker image
2. submit it to the registry
3. Uses that same image in the following steps to perform the tests.

```
Container(image:A): build image B 
Container(image:B) : test image B
```

So I would like to use variables and substitute them inside the kubernetes podtemplate as here:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage("Build image"){
        // some script that builds the image
        steps{
            script{
                def image_name = "busybox"
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Run tests') {
      environment {
        image = "$image_name"
      }
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          yaml """\
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          labels:
            some-label: some-label-value
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: busybox
            image: "${env.image}"
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
        """.stripIndent()
        }
      }
      steps {
        container('busybox') {
          sh 'echo "I am alive!!"'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the variable is empty as I get:

```
[Normal][ci/test-10-g91lr-xtc20-s1ng1][Pulling] Pulling image "null"
[Warning][ci/test-10-g91lr-xtc20-s1ng1][Failed] Error: ErrImagePull
[Warning][ci/test-10-g91lr-xtc20-s1ng1][Failed] Failed to pull image "null": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for null, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Do you know how I can achieve a similar behaviour ?

Comment: Note: I have seen that if I add the `environment {}` as child of `pipeline{}` it works but it is not what I want to achieve as I want that the image is generated from the previous step, and not that is hardcorded in the pipeline

Comment: Try to set `env.image = 'busybox'` directly in stage "build image" and remove `environment` block from "run tests".

Answer (score 2):

Thank you zett42 for your answer, I was able to achieve my objective with your suggestions.

Basically the solution was to set in the build stage a global environment variable. I post here the full solution to help others in my same problem:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage("Build image"){
        // some script that builds the image
        steps{
            script{
                env.image_name = "busybox"
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Run tests') {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          yaml """\
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          labels:
            some-label: some-label-value
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: busybox
            image: "${env.image_name}"
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
        """.stripIndent()
        }
      }
      steps {
        container('busybox') {
          sh 'echo "I am alive!!"'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To better understand it it was useful to read this article:

https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/